# Unable to load AWS credentials on EC2 Instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

**The application**

Simple REST API registration service in Spring, after sending proper POST request new user is created in database and Amazon SES sends an email with registration link to verify.

**The problem**

Locally after setting local variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`) in my OS (Windows) app works just fine, but the problem starts after deploying it. I have an EC2 Instance with Amazon Linux AMI on AWS:

- created user at AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM), granted AmazonSESFullAccess role
- logging by CMD using shh with the private key file *.pem
- Tomcat8 service started
- MySQL service started
- application *.war file deployed
- created environment variables  using 'export' command and I checked 'printenv' just to be sure everything is fine
- after sending POST request I got exception (below) which means that user has been created but Amazon SES didn't send an email confirmation because couldn't authenticate

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-26T15:44:44.010+0000",
    "message": "Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@23fac1a3: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@68aa5a98: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/]"
}
```

- I checked again local environment variables on my EC2 instance and it was looking fine but to be sure I re-configured it using 'aws configure' command
- exception keeps showing, somehow application cannot get environment variables, I'm fighting with that for over 5 hours now so hopefully someone will come here to rescue me...

Piece of code (works fine locally):

```
        AmazonSimpleEmailService client =
                AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
                        .standard()
                        .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                        .withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1)
                        .build();
```

I am total Linux noob, having problems with simple commands so please be gentle with solutions requiring some console commands.

Comment: run printenv to list all environment variables and share/verify the AWS keys are present. Also, check the ~/.aws/credentials file too

Comment: According to the error you have to add some additional dependencies ( aws-java-sdk-sts): `WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path`

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I believe they only need to include that dependency if they are using AWS profiles. I do not think they are using AWS profiles, since they are attempting to store credentials locally on the server.

Comment: As I mentioned, 'printenv' shows set variables correctly. The problem is solved by @Oleksii Donoha solution, thanks for replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running app on EC2, don't use IAM user.

Instead create IAM **role** with same permissions and assign that role to the instance. If app uses AWS SDK it will be able to pick up credentials without any problems.

In your case problem is probably app's environment being different from yours, if you export credentials in your bash session it will not pass to app if it's loaded under different user or bash session.

Comment: Creating role in IAM with AmazonsSESFullAccess and assigning it to EC2 instance solved the problem. I thought it may be user problem but didn't expect solution to be that simple... Many thanks.

Comment: I would strengthen the statement from "you don't have to use IAM user" to "do not use an IAM user".

Comment: @jarmod I mean, you **can**, it's an anti-pattern, but you can. But I agree, will edit that.

Answer (score 2):

The DefaultAWSCredentialsProvider has multiple places it will look for credentials. Instead of setting up your credentials as an environment variable, you can set up a credentials profile. See this documentation: [Working with AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

Make sure you have the [AWS CLI installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html), then you can run the following command to configure your profile: *aws configure*

Click [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) for the documentation on the aws configure command.

If you have already configured your aws profile and it still does not work, you have most likely configured the profile for the wrong linux user. For example, if a linux user named tomcat8 is the user who is running your tomcat instance, then you need to set up a credentials profile at /home/tomcat8/.aws/credentials/

Comment: As I mentioned I have already used AWS CLI to configure AWS credentials by using 'aws configure'. Credentials are set, still the error occurs. The problem is solved thanks to @Oleksii Donoha reply by setting IAM role to EC2 instance instead of user.